# Magento 301 htacess redirect not working at all

Tags: .htaccess, magento

i am writing a 301 redirects via htaccess redirect old traffic to new urls
ex
i have old url

http://www.thebedroom.com.au/catalogue/accessories/product134

i need to redirect this request to

http://www.thebedroom.com.au/melbourne-demons-bean-bag-cover.html

so i wrote a code on magento httpacess like below

```
Redirect 301 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/catalogue/accessories/product134 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/melbourne-demons-bean-bag-cover.html
```

no luck

and also tried

```
Redirect 301 ^accessories/product134 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/melbourne-demons-bean-bag-cover.html
```

but this not redirectoring and show the same url on browser window.

anyone know what is the issue here

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Redirect 301 /catalogue/accessories/product134 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/melbourne-demons-bean-bag-cover.html
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 product134 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/melbourne-demons-bean-bag-cover.html
```

which will redirect if there's any instance of `product134` in the URI.